# Querying a large table using mysql

Tags: mysql

I manage a property website. I have a table with banned users (small table) and a table called advert_views which keeps track of each listing that each user views (currently 1.3m lines and growing). The advert_views table alsio takes note of the IP address for every advert viewed).

I want to get the IP addresses used by the banned users and check if any of these banned users have opened new accounts. I ran the following query:

```
SELECT adviews.user_id AS 'banned user_id', 
       adviews.client_ip AS 'IPs used by banned users', 
       adviews2.user_id AS 'banned users that opened a new account'
FROM banned_users
LEFT JOIN users on users.email_address = banned_users.email_address  #since I don't store the user_id in banned_users
LEFT JOIN advert_views adviews ON adviews.user_id = users.id AND adviews.user_id IS NOT NULL # users may view listings when not logged in but they have restricted access to the information on the listing
LEFT JOIN (SELECT client_ip,
                  user_id 
                  FROM advert_views 
                  WHERE user_id IS NOT NULL   
                ) adviews2 
                ON adviews2.client_ip = adviews.client_ip
WHERE banned_users.rec_status = 1 and adviews.user_id <> adviews2.user_id
GROUP BY adviews2.user_id
```

I applied an index on the advert_views table and the users table as per below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj41B.png)

My query takes half an hour to execute. Is there a way how to improve my query speed?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Please show the query plan

Comment: IP addresses are a rather dangerous way to do this.  Many IP addresses are shared among many different people.

Comment: Should you be using a time limit for re-use of the IP address as well? People can request a new IP Address and it is a common way of avoiding banning attempts. What may be more useful is a reverse lookup of their current ip address. You may find that the hosting service points it to the same customer id. Mine does ;-/. Obviously, if any of the anonymous methods are used then this method is useless.

Comment: considered using a 'super cookie'? why should the the 'bad guys' have all the fun?

Comment: Thanks all! I take your points re IP addresses and will speak to the developer regarding the super cookie. Didn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Why do you outer join the tables? Or better: Why do you *try* to outer join the tables? A left join is meant to get data from a table even when there is no match. But then your results could contain rows with all values null. (That doesn't happen though, because `adviews.user_id <> adviews2.user_id` in your where clause dismisses all outer-joined rows.) Don't give the DBMS more work to do than necessary. If you want inner joins, then don't outer join. (Though the difference in execution time won't be huge.)

Next: You select from banned_users, but you only use it to check existence. You shouldn't do this. Use an `EXISTS` or `IN` clause instead. (This is mainly for readability and in order not to produce duplicate results. This probably won't speed things up.)

```
SELECT av1.user_id AS 'banned user_id', 
       av2.client_ip AS 'IPs used by banned users', 
       av2.user_id AS 'banned users that opened a new account'
FROM adviews av1
JOIN adviews av2 ON av2.client_ip = av1.client_ip AND av2.user_id <> av1.user_id
WHERE av1.user_id IN 
(
  SELECT user_id 
  FROM users 
  WHERE email_address IN (select email_address from banned_users where rec_status = 1)
)
GROUP BY av2.user_id;
```

You may replace the inner `IN` clause with a join. It's mostly a matter of personal preference, but it is also that in the past MySQL sometimes didn't perform well on `IN` clauses, so many people made it a habit to join instead.

```
WHERE av1.user_id IN 
(
  SELECT u.user_id 
  FROM users u
  JOIN banned_users bu ON bu.email_address = u.email_address
  WHERE bu.rec_status = 1
)
```

At last consider removing the `GROUP BY` clause. It reduces your results to one row per reusing user_id, showing one of its related banned user_ids (arbitrarily chosen in case there is more than one). I don't know your tables. Are you getting many records per reusing user_id? If not, remove the clause.

As to indexes I suggest:

- banned_users(rec_status, email_address)
- users(email_address, user_id)
- adviews(user_id, client_ip)
- adviews(client_ip, user_id)

Comment: Hi Thorsten thanks a lot for helping out! I really appreciate. I would never have arrived to your syntax alone. The reason why I joined 'banned_users' with 'the users' table is that I don't keep the user_id in the banned_users table. I take your point re group by - but I noticed that there are more than one user_id attached to an client ip sometimes. I will add the indexes you suggested. Without the indexes the run time improved by 3mintues :S

Comment: Ah, you are right, I missed that `banned_users` doesn't have a `user_id`. Sorry. So you'd have to join that table in the subquery or use a nested `IN` clause (`where av.user_id in (select user_id from users where email_address in (select email_address from banned_users where rec_status = 1))`. Instead of the index `banned_users(rec_status, user_id)` I suggest `banned_users(rec_status, email_address)` and `users(email_address, user_id)` then.

Comment: Thanks so much Thorsten!